How to focus the canvas pane in Inkscape?
I have an invisible object, which I can only select in the layers view. After selecting the object, I need to press Shift + S in order to toggle between handle types. This does not work when the layers dock has the focus. How do I focus the canvas, without losing selection?
I have tried:

In the keyboard and mouse reference, search for switch.
Finding a shortcut in the layers and objects shortcut list


Under Dialogs, find

Within a dialog
Esc return to the canvas

